# Aumentar/Diminuir progresso do SeekBar com ação de um Button?

Tags: java, android

Alguém pode ajudar: Como aumentar e diminuir o progresso do seekBarHomem através da ação do  Button?

[image: seekBar]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tv_QtdHomem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_QtdHomem);


    bt_MenosHomem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_MenosHomem);
    bt_MaisHomem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_MaisHomem);


    seekBarHomem = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarHomem);


    seekBarHomem.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public  void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                 tv_QtdHomem.setText(""+i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    bt_MaisHomem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });

   bt_MenosHomem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Quais os métodos de `SeekBar`? Pode ser a documentação da classe. Deve ter algum método como `seekBar.setProgress(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar os métodos `setProgress` e `getProgress` do `SeekBar`:

```
bt_MaisHomem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        seekBarHomem.setProgress(seekBarHomem.getProgress() + 1)
    }
});
```